# Override a specific Action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, custom-action-filter

In my WebApi 2 application, I've an action filter attribute in my base controller, this attribute has a boolean property with a default value which could be set in the constructor:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public bool MyProperty {get; set;}

  public MyActionFilterAttribute(bool myProperty = true)
  {
    MyProperty = myProperty;
  }

  public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
  {
    if(MyProperty)
    {
        //DO Something
    }
  }
}
```

I've also a `CustomValidatorFilter` configured in webApi config:

```
config.Filters.Add(new CustomValidatorFilterAttribute());
```

In some actions of my controller, I want to override the behaviour of MyActionFilterAttribute  by setting the value of `MyProperty` to `false`, I've added the `OverrideActionFilters` to my action:

```
[OverrideActionFilters]
[MyActionFilterAttribute(myProperty: false)]
public IHttpActionResult MyCation()
{
  //Some staff here
}
```

But now my custom validation not working any more because of use of `OverrideActionFilters`, Is there any way to redefine the OverrideActionFilters, or just to list the filter to override.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you clarify how does this correspond to question title?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to update the title

Comment: Well, first, Authorization filters should not be Action filters.  That's why `IAuthorizationFilter`s exist.  They run at a different point in the lifecycle (before action filters) and they also are passed an AuthorizationContext which ActionFilters do not.  You could easily build a mechanism to make the filter do nothing if a certain value is set

Comment: Assume that is not an authorization attribute, just a simple filter, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I've created a specific attribute `DoMyPropertyAttribute` and then I removed the property from the `MyActionFilterAttribute`.
In `MyActionFilterAttribute` I check if the action has `DoMyPropertyAttribute, if so I do the specific work:

```
public class DoMyPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
  {
    if(actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<DoMyPropertyAttribute>().Any())
    {
        //DO Something
    }
  }
}
```

In general, if we want override an action filter, we have just to skip it and then create a specific action filter that match the desired behaviour.
To skip an action filter we can do:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
  {
    if(actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<SkipMyActionFilterAttribute>().Any())
     {
       return;
     }

    //Do something
  }
}
```